# Remove field from object list in class

Tags: apex, json, list, sobject

I have list of accounts and want to use them for post request. How can I remove unnecessary fields like id to set that list in setbody?
Now I am just using for loop and json serialize.

Some code. So I need remove id and some other fields. Maybe use Map with key?

```
Http http = new http();
HttpRequest request = new httprequest();
request.setHeader();
for(Account acc: accList){
String body = json.serialize(acc);
request.setbody(body);
```

}

Upd: AccList is just a list of recently created account records.It’s in trigger so Trigger.new.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DavidReed tried what wrote. And parser, but I don’t get how to remove exact field. So I have only list and for loop for it.

Comment: Where are you getting `accList` from? Your code sample is incomplete.

Comment: @AdrianLarson it’s just recently created account records . Trigger.new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do what you want is use `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`, then remove any fields you want to block.

```
Map<String, Object> fields = acc.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
fields.remove('Id');
// etc
request.setBody(JSON.serialize(fields));
```

Comment: Looks good, but I don’t really want convert to map. But couldn’t fount better way. Thanks.